# Source For Different Streams of Judaism

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How loyal have Chassidim, Charedim, and Tzionim been to their source texts, [Sefer Chassidim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Hasidim), [Sefer Charedim](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhe.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D7%25A1%25D7%25A4%25D7%25A8_%25D7%2597%25D7%25A8%25D7%2593%25D7%2599%25D7%259D&ei=bW7qVPvaFIKqgwTz9oHoDg&usg=AFQjCNGCiHhvj1mHPvoq2xgdDy42l5iucg&bvm=bv.86475890,d.eXY), and [Sefer Hatzioni](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hebrewbooks.org%2F42374&ei=r27qVMC7AY-INsmIg5AI&usg=AFQjCNEoGWbhzSVqLHc7jpYB0UYn78cjdg&bvm=bv.86475890,d.eXY), respectively?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: For best humorous effect, run the link to [Sefer Charedim](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D) through [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/).

Comment: Favorite phrase so far: "The name of the book "anxious" given to him by his friend, the name of the great awe and anxiety consumed his opinion observance."

Comment: Should this be closed as "off  topic - Jews/history of the Jews not Judaism"? mevaqesh, can you explain how this question asks about [misinterpreting a real Torah concept or Jewish text OR applying a distinctly Torah style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an irrelevant topic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated?cb=1)?

Comment: (*Side note: there are other things you can do with the basis of this question (names of ספרים that sound like they correspond to streams of Judaism) that should be on topic here*)

Comment: @Shokhet Simple it misinterprets the title (interpreting each as a proper noun), just as many such questions misinterpret verses and the like.

Comment: Okay, that might work. I won't take back my close vote, because I'm still not sure; let's see what the review queue makes of this.